# In jquery cycle2 plugin - execute cycle-after only particular slide is active

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

With jquery cycle2 plugin,

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

would it be possible to amend the below code so that the cycle-after only executes on a particular slide - the slide could be identified by:

- an id in the markup on the slide
- the slideNum (as can be pulled using the api)
- the data-cycle-hash assigned to the slide

I have checked the api and cannot find any details on such an event:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl,     incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
$('.tester').addClass('changer'); 
});

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested I have achieved this by giving this slides IDs and using an if statement with .is to get the id of the incoming slide. I'm sure there's a better way to do it but this seems to work. See below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after',function(e, optionHash, outgoingSlideEl,         incomingSlideEl, forwardFlag){
var now = $(incomingSlideEl)
if (now.is(#chosenslide)){
$('.tester').addClass('changer'); 
});

});
</script>
```